# Cannot order destinations alphabetically

Tags: php, wordpress, alphabetical

I have unordered destinations, which i print in the following way:

```
$destinations = get_posts( array(
                            'post_type' => 'destination_showcase',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'destination_state',
                                    'value' => ':"'.$state_id . '";' , // looking for serialized value in quotes
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            ),
                        ) );
```

I want to print the destinations alphabetically. When i var_dump-ed the #destinations array i got all of the destinations and their parameters. I want to get their titles i.e "post_title" and print it alphaberically. I've tried this, but doesn't work:

```
'orderby'=> $destinations->post_title, 'order' => 'ASC',
```

Any ideas how the task can be done ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `'orderby'=> 'post_title'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try this

```
$destinations = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'destination_showcase',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'destination_state',
            'value' => ':"'.$state_id . '";' , // looking for serialized value in quotes
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
) );
```

Answer (score 1):

If I read the [WP Query manua](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)l properly, this should work:

```
  get_posts( array(
                        'post_type' => 'destination_showcase',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'destination_state',
                                'value' => ':"'.$state_id . '";' , 
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                            )

                        ),
                      'orderby' => 'title',
                      'order'   => 'ASC',
                    ) );
```